# Python: What is the best way of organizing this thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I would like to know which is the best way of organizing the thread I have in my code. This is an example of the function I call in the thread:

```
def func(param1, param2, **kwargs):
    r = requests.get(param1 + param2)
    ... do something ...
    if "queue" in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs["queue"], queue.Queue):
        kwargs["queue"].put(r)
    else:
        return r
```

Then this function gets called here:

```
def thread_func(list_):
    q = queue.Queue()
    for item in list_:
        t = threading.Thread(target = func1, args = (item[0], item[1],), kwargs = {"queue" : q})
        t.start()
    t.join()
    return q
```

The function func may be also called outside the thread (for a single request) or inside the thread, so I thought to pass a queue in the kwargs if it's called inside the thread and if a queue is passed, instead of returning the result it puts it into the queue.

Also I read I may use a Pool to do this but I don't know in advance how many threads I would need.

Speed of execution is important for me and I was wondering, if you think there is a way to improve the current code.

For example, I think it would be better to insert the returned values from func directly in a list, instead of putting then in a list later by looping through the Queue, however I read Queues are the preferred objects where to store threads results, so not sure it's a good practice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use two separate functions, where a wrapper uses the plain version. Something like this:

```
def normal_func(param1, param2):
    r = requests.get(param1 + param2)
    ... do something ...
    return r

def thread_func(param1, param2, queue):
    queue.put(normal_func(param1, param2))  # Use the bare-bones version
```

Then use the first version when you want "normal" behavior, and the second when multithreading:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=thread_func, args=(item[0], item[1], q))
```

Trying to combine fundamentally different behavior in one function is messy.